# Python- get specific lines from a file and iterate

Tags: python, file

I have a file like:

```
Hi=1
How=2
Are=3
You=4
Thank=5 
You=6 
Will=7 
Be=8  
Better=9

Hi=10
How=11
Are=12
You=13
Thank=14 
You=15 
Will=16 
Be=17  
Better=18
```

I want to get every (for example) 1st, 3rd, 5th row and store it in a list. Getting specific  row is easy, i know, with `linecache` with `enumarate` with `itertools` and so on. 
But as you can see I have the same amount of lines iterating in the file, so after getting 1st, 3rd, 5th rows from first verse, I have to get the 1st, 3rd, 5th rows from second verse..

So I want to get smt similar to:

```
>>>print "This is 1st row %s" %var1
>>>print "This is 3rd row %s" %var2
>>>print "This is 5th row %s" %var3
This is 1st row Hi=1 Hi=10
This is 3rd row Are=3 Are=12
This is 5th row Thank=5 Thank=14
```

Thank you for your help in advance..

EDIT:

With respect to comments, in the real file there are over 60.000 verses present..
Each verse is separated with a `=` sign..

Comment: Will there always be 2 verses?

Comment: Hi jamylak. No, there are like 60.000 verses present..

Comment: that is **definitely** something you should mention in the question. By any chance do you know the length of the verses in advance?

Comment: It is also handy to know if your verses are always separated by an empty line.

Comment: Info added to question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this using a `defaultdict(list)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
with open("abc") as f:
    dic=defaultdict(list)
    i=1
    for line in f:
          line=line.strip()
          if line:
             dic[i].append(line)
             i+=1
          else:
             i=1

for i in range(1,10,2):   #get the 1,3,5,7,9 line
   print "This is row {0}: {1}".format(i," ".join(dic[i]))

print

for i in [1,4,8]:        #get the 1,4,8 line
   print "This is row {0}: {1}".format(i," ".join(dic[i]))
```

**output:**

```
This is row 1: Hi=1 Hi=10
This is row 3: Are=3 Are=12
This is row 5: Thank=5 Thank=14
This is row 7: Will=7 Will=16
This is row 9: Better=9 Better=18

This is row 1: Hi=1 Hi=10
This is row 4: You=4 You=13
This is row 8: Be=8 Be=17
```

Comment: This is a lot more elegant than what I was thinking off, +1

Comment: Hi Ashwini, This seems to do the job! 
What if I want to get 1st, 4th, 8th rows? I am asking this because you are incrementing line number by 2..

Comment: @teutara Well in that case you've to increment `i` by some different value and skip more number of lines.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But 1st-4th-8th rows example indicates that i is not static. To pass 4th row from 1st row, i would be 3, then from 4th row to 8th row i have to be 4.. How to overcome this?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary You are now just storing every single line, that may or may not be a problem. Although this wasn't specified in the original question

Comment: @jamylak As OP's requirements are not fixed, so we may have to store each line.

Comment: @teutara could you please include include all requirements in your original question?

Answer (score 1):

Explanation: `verses` is a `list` that contains all the verses in the text.

`indexes` is a `list` that contains all the lines you want to print.

At the end, in order to print the results, a simple use of `zip` do the work:

```
  txt = """Hi=1
How=2
Are=3
You=4
Thank=5 
You=6 
Will=7 
Be=8  
Better=9

Hi=10
How=11
Are=12
You=13
Thank=14 
You=15 
Will=16 
Be=17  
Better=18"""

verses = [[]]
for line in txt.splitlines():
    if line != "":
        verses[len(verses)-1] += [line]
    else:
        verses += [[]]

indexes = [1, 3, 5]
for i, line in enumerate(zip(*verses)):
    if i+1 in indexes:
        print("This is {} row {}".format(i+1, " ".join(line)))
```

Output:

```
This is 1 row Hi=1 Hi=10
This is 3 row Are=3 Are=12
This is 5 row Thank=5  Thank=14
```

Comment: You can also use `indexes=range(1,len(verses[0])+1,2)` and your `print` statement will only work for two verses, better use : `print("This is {} row {}".format(i+1, " ".join(line)))`

Comment: You're right,I missed the fact that OP's expected output was just an example.